# How can I break up my code so Xcode will let my run my App | SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui

I get this error

> The compiler is unable to type-check this expression in reasonable time; try breaking up the expression into distinct sub-expressions

The code why the error happens is like this:

```
ForEach(items){ item in
                    var abgektItem = abgehakt.first(where: {i in i.id == item.id})
                    var normalItem = abgektItem.normalItem
                    var normalItemAnzahl = normalItemAnzahl ?? 0
                    var anzhal = item.normalItem!.Anzahl - normalItemAnzahl
                    someView(anzhal)
                }.padding(.vertical)
```

I simplified the code.
How can I *break up the code* even more? I mean I mead for every single step a new variable...

Thanks for your help, Boothosh

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This often means you have a bug, not that the expression is actually too complex. For example, these lines are incorrect:

```
var abgektItem = abgehakt.first(where: {i in i.id == item.id})
var normalItem = abgektItem.normalItem
```

`first(where:)` returns an Optional, so `abgektItem.normalItem` is not valid. Sometimes determining that incorrect code is definitely incorrect (i.e. that there is *no* way that with type promotion or coercion or some protocol extension that it could be made to work) is combinatorially explosive, which is what leads to this message rather than a proper error.

Generally the best way to debug this (and for more readable code generally) is to move the computation to a function:

```
ForEach(items) { item in computeView(item) }
```

where `computeView` is a local function along the lines of:

```
func computeView(_ item: Item) -> some View {
    // compute
    return someView(anzhal)
}
```

If you move this code to a new `computeView` function, the compiler will almost certainly find your bug quickly.

Comment: Oh my god I found the Bug it was so dumb... (I only found it with your solution to move the View into a function). You saved my day, thank you!

Answer (score -3):

i already have this message, its when you put too much logic in your view, do the check etc in your viewModel and it will be fine

Comment: That was already their understanding of the cause. They are asking _how_ to simplify the logic. As for moving the logic to the view model, can you clarify what you mean? If you’re suggesting doing that just to get more **meaningful compiler errors**, that’s what [@Rob’s answer from several hours ago](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70566988/3025856) suggests, but with a lot more clarity and detail. If you’re suggesting that simply moving it will **solve** the problem, that doesn’t seem to be the case based again on [Rob’s accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70566988/3025856).

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).